# Python Regex: dealing with 4 patterns using re.search() and if statement once

Tags: python, regex

For example, below are the 4 patterns existing in a list of strings and results to be returned:

Pattern 1: `'A: 45'` --> 45 (45 - 0)

Pattern 2: `'B: 34'` --> -34 (0 - 34)

Pattern 3: `'A: 45, B: 34'` --> 11 (45 - 34)

Pattern 4: `'B: 34, A: 45'` --> 11 (45 - 34)

Is it possible that using `re.search()` only once and one `if` statement to achieve this? If not, are there alternative ways? Many thanks!

The method I came up with is

```
match = (re.search(r'(A: (\d+))?(B: (\d+))?', str))
if match:
    print(float(match.group(2)) - float(match.group(4)))
```

which only deals with the first 3 conditions and will throws an error for the the first conditions as either `match.group(2)` or `match.group(4)` is `NaN`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go (with a combination of a regex and tuple unpacking):

```
import re

strings = ['A: 45', 'B: 34', 'A: 45, B: 34', 'B: 34, A: 45']
rx = re.compile(r'([AB]): (\d+)')

for string in strings:
    groups = [m.groups() for m in rx.finditer(string)]
    sum = 0
    for group in groups:
        (letter, value) = group
        if letter == 'A':
            sum += float(value)
        elif letter == 'B':
            sum -= float(value)
    print(sum)
```

---

You can have it somewhat shorter with a list comprehension and the ternary operator (look it up :)), like so:

```
import re

strings = ['A: 45', 'B: 34', 'A: 45, B: 34', 'B: 34, A: 45']
rx = re.compile(r'([AB]): (\d+)')

def calc(groups):
    sum = 0
    for group in groups:
        (letter, value) = group
        c = float(value) if letter == 'A' else -float(value)
        sum += c
    return sum

results = [(string, calc(groups)) \
            for string in strings \
            for groups in [rx.findall(string)]]
print(results)
# [('A: 45', 45.0), ('B: 34', -34.0), ('A: 45, B: 34', 11.0), ('B: 34, A: 45', 11.0)]
```

---

See [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/shXnZf).

Comment: Thanks @Jan, that is inspiring. Just wondering, is there a way to do this using only `if`, no `elif` or `else`?

Comment: why is this a constraint?

Comment: @NateMara: So do I :)

Comment: @Map: You can use a ternary operator but please put readability before code shortening.

Comment: @BryceDrew: It is not in my opinion. Added an example nevertheless.

Comment: @Jan Thanks a lot. The way I did in the end was `match = dict(re.findall(r'(A|B): (\d+)', string))` `if  match:` `float(match.get('A', 0)) - float(match.get('B', 0))`

Comment: @Jan and I am sorry I didn't know this sort of discussion is discouraged on stackoverflow since I am new here. I think I am going to delete this question in case it is downvoted further.